# Dirichlet integral using real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, improper-integrals

The teacher made this approach to solve the Dirichlet integral ,
$$ J_n= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sin(2nx)}{\sin x}\:\mathrm{d}x,\quad I_n = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sin(2n+1)x}{\sin x}\:\mathrm{d}x $$
- Calculate  $$ J_n -J_{n-1}$$  and $$ I_n -I_{n-1} $$ 
 -Conclude  $$I_n  , J_n$$

This exercises was part of the Dirichlet integral exercise, I did calculated  $I_n $, $ I_n = \frac{\pi}{2}$. The problem I had with  $J_n$; I used all the Trig Formulae  I can think of, didn't get to simpler result like I did with $I_n$ where you find that $I_n -I_{n-1} = 0$ then easily conclude $I_n$.

---

I applied the formula mentioned above ,
Here's what I got :
$$ J_n -J_{n-1} = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{2}{2n-1}cos(2n-1)xdx  $$ So  $$ J_n -J_{n-1} = \frac{2}{2n-1}sin[(2n-1) \frac{\pi}{2}] $$ We can remarque that 2n-1 is not pair that means  $$ sin[(2n-1) \frac{\pi}{2}]  =+ 1$$ or $$ -1 $$ we can write $$ J_n -J_{n-1}= \frac{2(-1)^n}{2n-1}  $$
Then What should I do to find $$ J_n$$ ?

Comment: Hint: $\sin(A)-\sin(B) = 2\cos(\tfrac{A+B}{2})\sin(\tfrac{A-B}{2})$.

Comment: Anyone to help here !

Answer (score 0):

Using the Euler’s identity $z=e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, we can express the integrand in terms of $z$.
$$
\frac{\sin (2 n x)}{\sin x}=\frac{e^{2 n x i}-e^{-2 n x i}}{e^{x i}-e^{-x i}}=\frac{z^{2 n}-z^{-2 n}}{z-z^{-1}}= \frac{1}{z^{2 n-1}} \frac{z^{4 n}-1}{z^2-1}
$$
Expressing the last terms in summation
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sin (2 n x)}{\sin x} & =\frac{1}{z^{2 n-1}} \sum_{k=1}^{2 n} z^{2(2 n-k)} \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^{2 n} z^{2 n-2 k+1} \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n\left(z^{2 (n- k)+1}+\frac{1}{z^{2 (n-k)+1}}\right)\\&= \sum_{k=1}^n \left(z^{2(n-k)+1}+\overline{z^{2(n-k)+1}}\right)\\&= 2 \sum_{k=1}^n \cos (2(n-k)+1) x\\&= 2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos (2k+1) x
\end{aligned}
$$
Plugging back yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin (2 n x)}{\sin x} & =2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos (2k+1) x d x \\
& =2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\sin \left[(2k+1) \frac{\pi}{2}\right]}{2k+1}\\&= 2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{2 k+1}
\end{aligned}
$$